# Probability - Independence

Tags: probability

I am studying for the GMAT and have the following problem I cannot solve.

A box contains $M$ balls, of which $W$ are white. A sample of $n$ balls is drawn at random and without replacement. Let $A_j$ , where $j = 1, 2, \ldots , n$, denote the event that the ball drawn on the $j$-th draw is white. Let $B_k$ denote the event that the sample of balls contains exactly $k$ white balls.

a: Find the probability of $A_j$ .

b: Show that $P(A_j|B_k ) = \frac{k}n$.

I have found the probability of $A_j$ to be $\frac{W}M$ and this makes sense to me.

I can see that if b were reversed $P(B_k|A_j)$ then it would $= k/n$ as follows:
$$P(B_k|A_j)= P(B_j \cap A_j) / P(A_j)$$

The $P(A_j)$ in the numerator and denominator cancel out and we are left with:
$$P(B_k|A_j)= P(B_j)$$

We know that $P(B_j) = k/n$.

I'm not sure how to show the actual question for part b.

Comment: Are the ball identical?

Comment: I do not follow your logic for part b.  There is no P(Aj) in the numerator to "cancel out"!  And you seem to have switched the j and k subscripts for Bk.  And since when is P(Bj)=k/n??  The probability that a sample of n balls selected from the box of W white and (M-W) non-white has exactly k (or j) whites is NOT equal to k/n!

Comment: If we are given that Bk occurred, then we know that we have selected exactly k whites in our sample of n balls.  The probability that any one of the n balls is white (including the jth ball, or Aj) is k/n

Comment: Thanks Andrew.  You're right I had a type and my logic was wrong.  This makes sense!